# python pandas nested loop: to apply a function to each element of e.g. column 2 involving compounding same elements in previous column 1s

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas/data frame programming, and have not yet grasped implementing the equivalent of simple loops.

What I am essentially trying to implement is something like this:

```
counter = 0
for port in portfolios:
    for bin in bins:
        value[port[counter +1, bin]] 
        = port[counter + 1, bin] * port[counter, bin]
counter += 1
```

In fact, using an example table below, for each bin in each portfolio port, I am trying to multiply  `rebal_wgt [port=i,bin=j]` by  `rebal_wgt[port=i-1,bin=j]`.  I want to do this for all portfolios port (there are 11 of them), and all the bins within each portfolio port, such that each portfolio's corresponding bin gets multiplied by the previous portfolio's corresponding bin (e.g. `port5 bin 1 rebal_weight * port 4 bin 1's rebal_weight` etc.)

---

In fact, I think that what I am trying to achieve is a cumulative product.
From above,

```
value[port[counter +1, bin]] = port[counter + 1, bin]*port[counter, bin]
```

So it stands to reason that any value[port,bin] can be expressed as a product with the value[port-1,bin].  Thus, starting with value[0,bin], one can do cumulative product to derive the values of successive portfolios for each bin.  Which is what I would like to do! unfortunately I don't think the first answer given below does this as it doesn't loop over portfolios for each bin, it seems to loop over bins within each portfolio.  Any help much appreciated! a sample data table is below, ignore cum_ret_sum and stocks.

```
     port  bin   cum_ret_sum  stocks     rebal_wgt  
  0       0    0  4.067563e+03     216  1.883131e+01  
  1       0    1  1.300282e+04     213  6.104612e+01  
  2       0    2  1.426061e+04     214  6.663837e+01  
  3       0    3  4.904957e+02     205  2.392662e+00  
  4       0    4  1.100993e+04     209  5.267908e+01  
  5       0    5  4.630904e+03     208  2.226396e+01  
  6       0    6  1.019425e+04     215  4.741514e+01  
  7       0    7  2.249585e+04     213  1.056143e+02  
  8       0    8  8.831653e+03     214  4.126941e+01  
  9       0    9  3.098015e+05     212  1.461328e+03  
  10      1    0  1.881155e+00     267  7.045525e-03  
  11      1    1  7.486650e+00     280  2.673804e-02  
  12      1    2  4.492010e+00     268  1.676123e-02  
  13      1    3  1.191500e+01     273  4.364468e-02  
  14      1    4  4.388776e+00     266  1.649916e-02  
  15      1    5  1.384601e+01     270  5.128153e-02
```

Example output for bin = 0 (want this for all bin = 0 to bins)

```
port    bin rebal_wgt   rebal_wgt(port[counter,bin] * port[counter - 1, bin])
0   0   18.83131173675383   18.83131173675383
0   1   61.04612379316069   
0   2   66.63837376523843   
0   3   2.3926618103462602  
0   4   52.67907609709447   
0   5   22.26396127204363   
0   6   47.415137683181634  
0   7   105.61432751079496  
0   8   41.26940808193825   
0   9   1461.3276714958988  
1   0   0.0070455247063908755   0.13267647209504757
1   1   0.026738035817712412    
1   2   0.01676122975460385 
1   3   0.04364467915381678 
1   4   0.016499159440430355    
1   5   0.051281526270788164    
1   6   0.04977016623588389 
1   7   0.0645014820724396  
1   8   0.1438106018214078  
1   9   0.0340451076286303  
2   0   5.1196753262692285  0.6792604605614628
2   1   0.014870173557215314    
2   2   3.263374203937453   
2   3   73.32640040253595   
2   4   3.915173886409575   
2   5   67.46028895344207   
2   6   7.654613865824991   
2   7   12.837204120226547  
2   8   2983.065107673766   
2   9   0.4204701203425892  
3   0   71.16936245719319   48.34253392053873
```

Actual desired output:

```
port    bin rebal_wgt   rebal_wgt(port[counter,bin] * port[counter - 1, bin])
0   0   18.83131173675383   18.83131173675383
0   1   61.04612379316069   61.04612379316069
0   2   66.63837376523843   66.63837376523843
0   3   2.3926618103462602  2.3926618103462602
0   4   52.67907609709447   52.67907609709447
0   5   22.26396127204363   22.26396127204363
0   6   47.415137683181634  47.415137683181634
0   7   105.61432751079496  105.61432751079496
0   8   41.26940808193825   41.26940808193825
0   9   1461.3276714958988  1461.3276714958988
1   0   0.0070455247063908755   0.13267647209504757
1   1   0.026738035817712412    1.6322534445140364
1   2   0.01676122975460385 1.116941093152327
1   3   0.04364467915381678 0.10442695703615294
1   4   0.016499159440430355    0.8691604757005253
1   5   0.051281526270788164    1.1417299148641158
1   6   0.04977016623588389 2.3598592845892727
1   7   0.0645014820724396  6.812280652530306
1   8   0.1438106018214078  5.934978413076811
1   9   0.0340451076286303  49.75105785677358
2   0   5.1196753262692285  0.6792604605614628
2   1   0.014870173557215314    0.024271892009286238
2   2   3.263374203937453   3.6449967507110035
2   3   73.32640040253595   7.65725286445137
2   4   3.915173886409575   3.4029143975620206
2   5   67.46028895344207   77.02142996352207
2   6   7.654613865824991   18.06381160121289
2   7   12.837204120226547  87.45063726080163
2   8   2983.065107673766   17704.427018846454
2   9   0.4204701203425892  20.918833284208702
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### cumulative operation

---

```
In [5]:
df.groupby(df.bin)['rebal_wgt'].cumprod()
Out[5]:
0       18.831310
1       61.046120
2       66.638370
3        2.392662
4       52.679080
5       22.263960
6       47.415140
7      105.614300
8       41.269410
9     1461.328000
10       0.132676
11       1.632254
12       1.116941
13       0.104427
14       0.869161
15       1.141730
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is almost there, but want I need to do is multiply the numbers of the corresponding bins together, so it is e.g. (port1,bin0).rebal_wgt * (port0,bin0).rebal_wgt , (port1,bin1).rebal_wgt * (port0,bin1).rebal_wgt , ... (port_n,bin_n).rebal_wgt * (portn-1,bin_n).rebal_wgt , ... I tried to do this by using shift(bins), e.g. shift(10), but the problem is that this is not cumulative, i.e. I need to shift by 10 every result as its a cumulative product.  Is there another way, e.g. using groupby['port', 'bins'] that might be better/more intuitive?

Comment: can you post a sample of your desired result ?

Comment: sure, let me pull something together.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly , but does this work with you `df.groupby(df.bin)['rebal_wgt'].cumprod()` ? , if no post the desired result of your sample input

Comment: Thanks Nader, I think it really was this simple ... results seem the same as those I posted up.

Comment: In fact, it seems to me, that one could apply a similar method to calculations involving n nested loops.  As long as one has pre-calculated each of the n loops, and ordered them using sort, one can apply a function to the result by using groupby on the nth bin directly.  In the problem above, the loop was a 2-variable nested loop, with bin being at level 1, and port being at level 0.  This may relate to indexing?